# Struggling with logging (Flask/Module/Debug)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-multithreading

I have a web UI on top of a multi-threaded rules engine.  For the most part, the web UI is designed to provide standard CRUD services to the data gathered by the rules engine as well as start-up and shut-down of the rules services.

I want to attach the flask logger (current_app.logger) to the module-level logging output and then configure output logs for each running service.

Simple test with failure:
`rules.py` test function:

```
def stupid_logging_test():
    logging.debug('Will flask log me?')
```

`admin.py`:

```
@admin.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_root():
    #show the root admin page.
    servers = current_app.config['instance_servers']
    metrics = None
    if len(servers):
        metrics = compileMetrics(servers)
    # this includes starting/stopping rules engine and metrics
    adminform = ServerAdminForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if adminform.startserver.data:
            current_app.logger.info('performing rule server start.')
            start_source_servers()
            #current_app.logger.debug(pprint.pformat(form))
            #current_app.logger.debug(str(tabledata))
        elif adminform.stopserver.data:
            current_app.logger.info('performing rule server stop.')
            stop_source_servers()
            #current_app.logger.debug(pprint.pformat(form))
            #current_app.logger.debug(str(tabledata))
        else:
            current_app.logger.info('unknown submit?')
            current_app.logger.debug('debug line test.')
            rules.stupid_logging_test()

    return render_template("admin_main.html", adminform=adminform,
            metrics=metrics, servers=servers)
```

Logging output (console):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in admin [/<snip>/admin.py:51]:
unknown submit?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:ui:unknown submit?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in admin [/<snip>/admin.py:52]:
debug line test.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG:ui:debug line test.
```

`logging output (file)`:

```
unknown submit?
debug line test.
```

And finally here is my logging configuration (so far)

`ui:__init__.py`

```
# ... other app config
log_target = RotatingFileHandler(app.config['LOGFILE'], maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100, backupCount=20)
if 'DEBUG' in app.config and app.config['DEBUG']:
    log_target.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    log_target.setLevel(logging.WARN)
app.logger.addHandler(log_target)
rules_logger = getLogger('rules')
rules_logger.addHandler(log_target)
app.config['core_log'] = log_target
```

I get the feeling that my problem has to do with the getLogger method.  I am not giving the logger a name, but I assume the default is the name of the module itself?

Comment: in rules.py what is `logging` equal to?  you log `debug line test` to `current_app.logger` but in rules.py you log it to some `logging` variable that you have not provided, if they are different then obviously they will go to different logs.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen it's just the logging module.  There seems to be a bit of confusion about this in the documentation I've read.  if you configure a specific logger in a module the recommended method is to do ``mylogger = getLogger(__name__)`` however it also seems to be valid to simply use the logging module directly without configuring a specific logger.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen with the above said, a module-level ``logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`` also seems to fail.

Answer (score 0):

setting the loglevel on the handler was incorrect.  The following change resolved the issue:
`ui:__init__.py`:

```
log_target = RotatingFileHandler(app.config['LOGFILE'], maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100, backupCount=20)
loggers = [app.logger, getLogger('rules')]
for logger in loggers:
    if 'DEBUG' in app.config and app.config['DEBUG']:
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
    logger.addHandler(log_target)
app.config['core_log'] = log_target
```